# Dimension of homotopy equivalent CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $n$ and $m$-dimensional CW complexes. If $X\simeq Y$ then $n =m$? I think it's true but I don't know the reason.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}$ and a singleton $\lbrace \text{pt} \rbrace$?

Comment: @RobertMuller $\Bbb R$ is not a CW complex

Comment: It is an infinite CW-complex with $0$-cells being the integers.

Comment: Given that a point and an interval are homotopy equivalent, why would this be true?

Comment: @PaulFrost ah... right.

Comment: There are two notions of dimension of a finite CW complex, which *are* invariant up to homotopy.  gd$(X)$ is the smallest number $d$ with $X$ homotopy equivalent to a $d$-complex.  On the other hand cd$(X)$ is the smallest number $d$ with $H^s(X;A)=0$ for all $s>d$ and all coefficient systems $A$ (not just abelian groups but all modules over $\pi_1(X)$).  A major open question is if gd and cd are the same.  To disagree on a space $X$, the only possibility is that gd$(X)=3$ and cd$(X)=2$.  Candidates with cd$(X)=2$ have been proposed, but in each case it is unknown if gd$(X)=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X = \{0\}$ and $Y = [0,1]$. Then $X \simeq Y$, but $\dim X = 0  < 1 = \dim Y$.